# fleqn.clo vs fleqn.sty

Tags: document-classes

Please have a look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{JHEP}

\usepackage{fleqn}

 \author{me} 
 \abstract{a}
 \title{t}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a = b+1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

however it works,  i got warning

> inputting `fleqn.clo` instead of obsolete `fleqn.sty`

What is the difference between .clo and .sty? 
If i use `fleqn` as a document class option instead of the package, it gets ignored. Why?

My last question, i also got warning

> You have requested document class JHEP, but the document class
>   provides JHEP3.

using this class. Why is that?

[`JHEP` here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/jhep)

Comment: The average age of people answering this question is depressingly high:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is (apart from an initial banner which is irrelevant) the contents of `fleqn.sty`:

```
\@obsoletefile{fleqn.clo}{fleqn.sty}
\input{fleqn.clo}
\endinput
```

This is provided because some people might still have LaTeX 2.09 documents with a `\documentstyle` initial line, where packages were given as option to this command and needed, for this, the `.sty` extension.

Don't load this file if you're using a specialized class such as `JHEP` that is meant for submissions to a journal. Either the class provides support for the `fleqn` option or not, in which case the journal managers won't be happy if you use it.

Actually, the class supports the option, because it has

```
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\@OImess{}}   %\input{fleqn.clo}} IGNORED ...
```

followed by

```
\newcommand\@OImess[1]{\JHEP@ignol{OPTION '\CurrentOption'#1}}
```

which simply will tell you that the option is ignored. Loading `fleqn.clo` anyway would probably result in something bad.

Finally the warning you get is because the class is named `JHEP.cls`, but it has

```
\ProvidesClass{JHEP3} [2003/01/03 v3.1.2 LaTeX document class - F.N.]
```

Thus it's their fault.

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference apart from the warning. Prior to LaTeX2e (that is, before 1993) the latex 2.09 syntax was

```
\documentclass[fleqn,longtable,12pt]{article}
```

there was no separate `\documentclass` or `\usepackage`.

So when converting from LaTeX2.09 to LaTeX2e, most old "options" became packages to be loaded as

```
\usepackage{longtable}
```

But the build-in options (`12pt` and `fleqn` here) stayed as options. People often got that wrong so `fleqn.sty` was added so that either syntax worked but with a warning.